# I am getting error message ImportError: cannot import name 'onetime_file'" while import a python file

Tags: python

I am trying to import onetime_file from config  folderbut getting error message "ImportError: cannot import name 'onetime_file'"

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour),
read up on [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)
and provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
that reproduces your problem.

Comment: To import file from config folder use :  `from config_folder_name.onetime_file import` *

Answer (score 0):

sorry i can not comment the post yet. How did you tried to open the file?
The standard way is:

```
with open(PATH_FILE, 'r') as file:
```

Did you check the path was correct? Did you tried to put the absolute path instead of the relative one? Is your file writable or readable?